# How to make UIView.animate function to be sync?

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

So I have some function with animation:

```
func animateScan() {
        topConstraint.constant = frame.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5) {
            self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

I call `animateScan()` in my ViewController on button tap as a sync functions.  So after this function I call another function to present another ViewController.  In `animateScan()` I have animation with 2.5 duration, but UIView.animate, as I understand Is async function, so when I call it I just setup animation, and `animateScan()` finishes without waiting this 2.5sec.
So my question is, can I somehow force `animateScan()` function to wait this 2.5 animation? Can I make `UIVIew.animate` to be synchronous?

P.S. I don't want to use completion closure in `UIview.animate`.

Comment: "I don't want to use completion closure in `UIview.animate`" Why not?

Comment: This view is deep in views hierarchy(fourth) and I don't want to pass completion  through the whole hierarchy, and I have a little complex logic, so if I do this it will be a little mess in my code. So I just want to know can I just wait `UiView.animate` or not. If it's not possible then, I must go with completion.

Comment: If you implement “async await” you can “await” watch “Meet async/await”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your method up as an `async` method:

```
func animateScan() async {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        // ... whatever ...
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5) {
            // ... whatever ...
        } completion: { _ in
            continuation.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you call `animateScan()` by saying `await` in an `async` context, your code will magically pause and wait for completion before resuming.

Comment: Yes, I think about `withCheckedContinuation`, it works as  I want, but still in my views hierarchy I need to make all functions `async` and `await` their call to the top when I finally call `Task`.  
So, thank you `matt`, you answered my question. You can use continuations to await animation, but with deep hierarchy it's even more complex than with completions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make the animation synchronous as waiting for its completion would suspend the main thread and that is a very bad idea.  You should use the completion handlers.  That's why they exist.